# Python: Providing path to use package

Tags: python

I have access to a PC which uses Anaconda from Continuum. I do not have install privileges to the PC and I can only use the USB. So, I have installed Anaconda on my home PC.

I did post a similar thread earlier and it seemed to have worked last time based on suggestions but something has changed and I am not able to run the package.

The code I am using is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\newspaper-0.0.9.8\newspaper-    
0.0.9.8\newspaper')
from .newspaper import *
```

I downloaded the package, unzipped it on my home PC desktop from this location:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/newspaper

When I do import I do see newspaper pop up in my Pycharm editor but it gives error:

```
Unresolved reference newspaper
```

Edit:

I am using '.' as shows in the pic, the newspaper option doesn't show up otherwise:

[image]

Comment: why `.newspaper`? Shouldn't it be `newspaper` and the corresponding module path be `'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\newspaper-0.0.9.8\newspaper-0.0.9.8`?

Comment: :-) demonstating us a picture is inspiring. But likely your python interpreter doesn't see that picture. wouldn't be better to run the interactive interpreter and check which modules are visible from within the interpreter? Also, a library usually has `setup.py` which often supports `--user` to install in some user-accessible folders.

Comment: BTW many if not all packages included into Anaconda are also provided through the standard python `pypi` distribution machinery, so you could and generally should install them with `pip` installer, unless you have good reasons not to do it.

Comment: I am new to Python so your comments are kind of still above my head. Can you please explain what I need to do ?

Comment: Do you have access to python interpreter on the target PC? Can you run program there? Do you have enough privileges on the _target_ PC to install packages into python system path, or maybe, you have to opt with user-directories?

Comment: I am not sure what privileges I have there so to be 100% sure I want to implement the path method so that I can point this to package on USB and make it work.